# How to filter the response of opensearch API in the request?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, request, opensearch

I want to query an opensearch index and to retrieve only the _source inside the hits tag. I tried to make the request in Postman like:

```
GET: http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?q="product1234"?format=json?filter_path=hits.hits._source
```

but this also gets me the metadata and all the other informative fields, like:

```
{
    "took": 17,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 44,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 4.2769747,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "os_fcpq_index",
                "_id": "300",
                "_score": 4.2769747,
                "_source": {...
```

I want to be able to retrieve a json that contains only the values that are inside the _source tag, like:

```
[{'_source': {'product_id': '1234'...}}]
```

I also looked over the opensearch documentation and it is possible to use the argument filter_path, but in my example it seems I am missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `?` in your URL, you need to separate each query string parameter with `&` instead of `?`

```
GET: http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?q="product1234"&format=json&filter_path=hits.hits._source
                                                           ^           ^
                                                           |           |
```